# JQuery table sorter adds new row automatically in Angular JS table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tablesorter

Co's
I am very new to angularjs and jquery table sorter.
I am having a search page in angularjs using ng-repeat. Now, I am trying to add "sort" functionality using jquery table sorter. When I click the "sort" triangle icon from my table, Sorting is NOT happening.Instead, I can see a "empty row" added as below.[image: Please see the screenshot below]

Below is the simple code  I used for sorting. I am showing only one table from the below ( based on some condition).

```
$(function(){   
    $('#searchTable1').tablesorter();
    $('#searchTable2').tablesorter();
    $('#searchTable3').tablesorter();
    $('#searchTable4').tablesorter();
});
```

I am puzzled what is happening after i clicked the "sort icon".
After i clicked sort, no custom files called ( my application related), such as javascript / java files. So, I am not able to debug the problem.

When i tried with $watch, alert(), console() - This EMPTY row is NOT exists in my JSON object ( namely searchReasults here).

Kindly help me on this...

Comment: Without answering to your question, you don't need to repeat the jQuery ready function. All code that is put inside `$(function(){ });` will work once DOM is ready. So your code should looks to `$(function(){ $('#searchTable1').tablesorter(); $('#searchTable2').tablesorter(); // etc.. });`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-). I modified the code as you suggested. But, this doesn't solves the problem. Still, the empty row added as shown in the screenshot. I have edited the code in my question also.

Comment: I am not much familiarized with angularJS but the problem looks to be in the tablesorter plugin. Try to debug the plugin: `$('#searchTable1').tablesorter({ debug: true; });`. I hope you can get some useful information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery table sorter on Angular dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259535/jquery-table-sorter-on-angular-dynamic-table)