# Jquery table sorter on Angular dynamic table

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a table that I required to use Jquery Tablesorter plugin to sort, amongst other things.

It works fine for static tables, but when I try to use on a Angular backed table, it does not work.

Does anyone know why that might be?

http://plnkr.co/edit/SUjs1h7prI3Xr8V2wiCP?p=preview

The table looks like this:

```
<table border="1" class="events-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td>{{ item.Fields["{BB2389F3-555B-4FC6-B106-C0A23A55A15F}"].Value }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Fields["{123A77C7-07D5-4CAA-85E0-8F9B9CEE110C}"].Value }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Fields["{B588A80F-A8C0-4A97-A35A-07D81ED53E9B}"].Value | formatData}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="data.length === 0">
      <td colspan="3">There are no events available to you.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve appears to be broadly identical to the worked example in [Advanced Directives - Combining AngularJS with Existing Components](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html).There will be about a day's work in understanding it, but maybe you are a faster learner than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the directive that did it:

```
$scope.data = filteredItems;
            console.log('success ');
            setTimeout(function(){
               $(".events-table").tablesorter({
                      widgets: ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"],
                      widgetOptions: {}
                });
            }, 500)
```